# How can I tell an SKTextureAtlas to stop animating and remove the object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

How can I tell the walk cycle to continue animating until an NSNumber with bool flag stops it?
And also remove the SKSpriteNode with the SKTexture from the stage?

```
    SKSpriteNode *walk = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[_walkTextures objectAtIndex:0]];
    walk.zPosition = 100;
    walk.scale = spliffScale;
    walk.position = location;

    [self addChild:walk];

    SKAction *walkAction = [SKAction animateWithTextures:_walkTextures timePerFrame:0.03];

    SKAction *remove = [SKAction removeFromParent];
    [walk runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[walkAction, walkAction, remove]]];
```

Comment: this is from the touchesBegan section

Comment: simple: [walk removeFromParent] ... no need to stop the animation if you remove the sprite. Also, to be precise: an SKTextureAtlas does not animate. A sprite can be animated by frequently changing its textures which may be sub-textures of a SKTextureAtlas. At best you could say "how to make a SKSpriteNode stop animating". ;)